Derivatives of the scaling factors with respect to the curvilinear coordinates
Lets assume we parametrise a surface by $(x_1,x_2)$. If the surface is parametrise in such a way that lines of constant $x_1$ and
$x_2$ are lines of curvature of the surface, and  the scaling factors associated to them are $h_1,h_2$.
What properties does the surface or parametrization need to have to lead to $\frac{\partial h_1}{\partial x_1}=\frac{\partial h_2}{\partial x_2}=0$?
By scaling factors I mean the lengths in the metric on the surface.
i really appreciate any help

By "scaling factors", do you mean the lengths (in the metric on the surface) of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ for $i = 1, 2$? If so, I suggest you consider a very simple surface, namely $P = \mathbb R^2$, so that the parameterization is simply a map from $P$ to $P$ that preserves vertical and horizontal lines, and see where that gets you.

@JohnHughes yes by scaling I mean the lengths in the metric tensor. When i consider a spherical or a cylinderical coordinate, the derivatives are zero, but I am not sure in if works in general, which is why I asked this question

The fact that the coordinate curves are lines of curvature is not particularly relevant to your question, since you're talking just about the metric and not how the surface is embedded in space. What if you just consider a reparametrization by $(f_1(x_1),f_2(x_2))$ for arbitrary diffeomorphisms $f_i$?

@TedShifrin if the shape tensor is diagonal, does that mean that the the derivatives of each scaling factors respect to its parametrization ($x_1$ or $x_2$) is zero?

@TedShifrin I am trying to understand what property in the spherical or cylinderical coordinate leads to the derivatives to be zero.

In answer to your last question, it's because you move at constant speed along the $x_i$-curves in those examples. The shape operator (and its eigenvectors/eigenvalues) has nothing to do with your question.

I have modified the question. Could you clarify what you mean by moving with constant speed? @TedShifrin

This is just a geometric/physical way of interpreting your partial derivative condition. The velocity vector of the $x_1$-curve has length $\sqrt{h_1}$ and the velocity vector of the $x_2$-curve has length $\sqrt{h_2}$. Zero partial derivatives means that these lengths do not change as you move along the respective $x_i$-curves.

Consider $f(x, y) = (x^3 + x, y)$. On the plane, this has the property that paths like
$$
h(x) = f(x, a)\\
v(y) = v(a, y)
$$
(for any fixed $a$) are in face horizontal and vertical lines, which are lines of curvature in the plane. Now check the lengths of the coordinate-path tangent vectors...

Well, every curve is a line of curvature. This issue continues to be a red herring. :)

I agree. Although one COULD wrap the second plane around a cylinder to make it more relevant. :)
